# Macbook Air Panic on Boot, "Unable to find driver for this platform: \"MacBookAir7,2\"

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, kernel-panic

I have a Macbook Air that isn't booting into macOS. I'm repairing it for a friend, and they said this issue started suddenly for no reason, but I can't be 100% sure.

Normally it hangs on the apple logo progress bar screen. Booting in verbose mode, I can see the first error is  `ACPI Error: Hardware did not change modes (20140828/hwacpi-ea)` followed by a few other ACPI Errors and then the panic with backtrace. I've attached a screenshot of the panic. This happens on normal boot, from the recovery partition, internet recovery, and a USB installer. The only thing that does work on it is an Ubuntu live USB, which works great. I've cleared the NVRAM and SMC, and I've also tried reformatting the SSD with no success. Apple Diagnostics also comes back with no errors. I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated![image: Verbose Screenshot]

Comment: I have the same exact thing on My MacBook Pro 13" late-2015: Unable to find driver for this platform: \"MacBookPro12,1\"